# Integrate Camera View in to my application in PhoneGap

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

According to PhoneGap Camera API, when I call 'camera.getPicture' it opens the default camera application of the phone.
Is there a way to prevent opening the default camera application but simply take the camera view to my application (to some panel) and override the picture capture functionality to a button in my application..? Any sample code is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With **PhoneGap** framework you can get access to **native** APIs. And you shouldn't override this functionality.